# Java Web Server with GUI

Tags: java, web-services

This is a web service method which simple add 1 to a counter when called(clicked) from a client. *display1* in the code is a static variable which is a text field in another class in the same package as the server. My problem is, every time I use the method from a client that uses the service, I get SOAP fault, Null pointer  exception. It points to the line  `display1.setText("20");`
as the cause. Is there any solution to this? Yes, the displaying has to be with the server btw and not a separate client.

```
        }@WebMethod(operationName = "next")
public int next(@WebParam(name = "counter") String counter, @WebParam(name = "type") String type) {
    int value = 0;
    if(iCounter >= iCounterMax) {
           value = iCounterMin;
           iCounter = iCounterMin;
       } else {
           value = iCounter++;
        }
        display1.setText("20");
        return value;                   
}
```

Comment: What's `display1`? (Other than null.)

Comment: An imported textfield.

Comment: "An imported textfield," what is that? I mean, it's obviously null. What *is* it? What *sets* it? etc.

Comment: You've included the line that references `display1`, but which line(s) declare or instantiate `display1`?  Your `next()` method assumes `display1` will have a value by the time it's called, somewhere in your code  you're calling `next()` before `display1` is being set.